# Can the Minor Illusion cantrip create a taxidermy look-alike of a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, illusion

The [*Minor Illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spell description states:

> You create a sound or an image of an object within range that lasts for the duration. (...) If you create an image of an object--such as a chair, muddy footprints, or a small chest--it must be no larger than a 5-foot cube. The image can't create sound, light, smell, or any other sensory effect.

It is clear that you cannot create the [image of a *creature*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55352/can-minor-illusion-look-like-a-creature-or-look-like-me), both for power reasons and by the wording of the spell.

But could you create something that **can easily be mistaken for a creature**, such as a stuffed taxidermy of a monster, a lifelike statue, or a fresh corpse?

The upvoted answer to the Q&A [Can Minor Illusion create sounds/images that the caster has never seen or heard?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116828/can-minor-illusion-create-sounds-images-that-the-caster-has-never-seen-or-heard) seems to suggest this would be possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, *minor illusion* can be used this way

Like you said, corpses, statues, and taxidermies are objects. *Minor illusion* can create illusions of objects. So, *minor illusion* can create illusions of those things.

You have all the dots, and it looks like you already connected them for me!

Answer (score 0):

### Technically, this is possible

A lifelike statue, a stuffed monster, an armor looking like a heavily armored fighter, or a corpse under 5e rules all [count as an *object*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/is-a-dead-creatures-body-considered-an-object), not as a creature.

The spell lists objects that are not resembling any creature, does not list creatures, but makes no explicit statement about the object not being able to resemble a creature. Neither does the list of exclusions.

These creature-lookalikes would not exhibit any movement, and it may be easier to discern that something is not right with them, either granting **Advantage** to the saving throw to reveal them as an illusion, or allowing observers to recognize that since it is not moving, it is not actually a creature. But on superficial inspection, under time pressure, or with difficult lighting conditions like dim light, it may be difficult for a casual observer to tell the difference.

The objects created by minor illusion have to be static, [they cannot move](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163940/can-the-minor-illusion-cantrip-create-an-animated-illusion-that-follows-a-creatu/163986#163986). This means the illusion of a taxidermied creature will for all practical purposes appear identical to the illusion of a creature. Possible differences would be extemely slight, such as the life-likeness of the eyes of the creature. In essence, this interpretation is way to circumvent that the spell does not mention illusions of creatures can be created.

I think if it was the intent of the spell to allow creating illusions of creatures, it would have mentioned them. The use of taxidermies to me smells of hair-splitting to extend the power of the spell. I would not be surprised if a DM ruled that this is against the spirit of the spell, and would limit the allowed use to statues or armors.